# Video Recording in @microsoft/teams-js Mobile Client

Tags: javascript, html5-video, microsoft-teams, video-capture, getusermedia

I'm working on a tabs based React app in Microsoft Teams using @microsoft/teams-js. The app is supposed to work in Browser, Team Desktop Client (iframe in Electron based client) and Teams Mobile client (iframe in unknown setup). I've been able to access image and video files, both uploads and recording/capture in both **Browser** and **Teams Desktop Client** following documentation. It were basically file inputs and `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` methods of HTML5.

But the **Mobile Client** requires calling `media.captureImage()` method of @microsoft/teams-js library. The official Documentation states that we will only be to upload or capture photos in the Mobile Client and no video access is possible, but I was able to get video upload to work using `<input type="file" />`. By using the `camera="camera"` prop I was even able to launch the native camera in mobile browsers (but not desktop browser, or the Teams Clients).

`<input type="file" accept="video/*" capture="camera" onChange={uploadVideoFile} />`

I want to know what other way is there to access camera for video recording in Teams Mobile  - be it native camera app or in app Media access.

Answer (score 0):

The APIs supported by Microsoft Teams are mentioned in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/device-capabilities/native-device-permissions?tabs=mobile). For other APIs please help by raising it on [user voice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/filters/new).